# How do I disable Microsoft Word cascade when I press enter (how to stop the text from moving)?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

When I use Microsoft Word and when I am writing a document with many pages, pressing enter makes all of the remaining text onward push down in the document. I don't want the text on subsequent pages to be moved because they were fine as is. How do I disable this?

Comment: You have to decrease the line spacing to achieve this. Else they will keep moving

Comment: Are you using proper page-breaks or setting multiple line-breaks to make it go to a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Page Break".

[image]

You can see the specific steps in the screen recording below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a multi-page document (all text, no pictures or tables, to keep things simple) and some paragraphs are all on one page and some are running from one page to the next. Just like the average novel.

I am sure that, when  you typed it, you only used the Enter key to start a new paragraph.

Now, move your mouse to any random place in any paragraph and click it. See the fine vertical line that appears? This is called the 'insertion point' by some people to allow the word cursor to apply specifically to the mouse. It shows where the next typed keyboard character will go.

Enter is a 'typed keyboard character', but it is also a command. Type it now. MS Word assumes that the Enter key is your command to start a new paragraph. Any text to the right of the insertion point will slip down to the next line on the page and become the start of a new paragraph.

I am sorry if I am preaching to the choir, but I need to be sure we share a vocabulary.

MS Word will also allow you to type Enter with the shift key held down. This is sometimes called a 'soft carriage return'.  It starts a new line, but any specific end-of-paragraph formatting set up earlier is ignored.

So, my answer is that Word's behaviour when you type Enter is correct. I do not know how to change ' the new paragraph' functionality of the Enter key.

Maybe I could be of more help if you described what you would like to see when you typed Enter.